# Windows Aero areas in own C# Applications

Tags: c#, windows, aero, aero-glass

I'm wondering about that many new applications, I think most built in WPF, has this really cool Windows Aero Glass interfaces.

For example Seesmic or the upcoming Firefox 3.7
[image: http://crenk.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/firefox3.7.jpg]
<sub>(source: [crenk.com](http://crenk.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/firefox3.7.jpg))</sub>

Searching in the internet most time it looks like you need a hack to realize this. But seriously: I don't think big software development teams use hacks to roll out their huge used products.

So my question is: **Windows Aero Glass Areas - How to do?**

Is it only possible with a hack?

Maybe it's just one property, i don't know. I'm WinForms developer so I never tested out WPF. But my Google search didn't look like It is easier with WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have Aero glass, you need to use the Desktop Window Manager. It is a Win32 DLL, so you need to P/Invoke it. Articles on how to do this are all over the Internet, ex. [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151222072655/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/adam_nathan/archive/2006/05/04/589686.aspx) Using P/Invoke is definitely not a hack.

Comment: You just gave me an idea for a bumper-sticker/t-shirt: "It's Not a Hack, It's an Interface".

Comment: Yeah, maybe a stupid question for you, guys. But I'm wondering why this isn't implemented as a form property or something else.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, for whatever reason Microsoft didn't include the DWM methods as "native WPF" (now there's an oxymoron) methods. Since they will check effort/benefit before adding such things to the code, who knows when there will be a WPF DWM?

Comment: My theory is that Microsoft is sensibly trying to keep software written for Windows separate from whatever flavor-of-the-month UI bells-and-whistles decorative crap they're trying to copy off of Apple at the moment.

Comment: Coming up next in Windows 7: the windows will look like they're floating over a reflective surface! Ooh!

Comment: Or perhaps spinning 3D-cubes... with transparent desktops on each face.

Comment: @DanielRose: The link you provided gives me a 403 Forbidden